# Excluding .svn folders when optimising with requirejs

Tags: javascript, svn, optimization, requirejs, r.js

I am attempting to optimise a project using r.js, with source code held in subversion. I'm getting the following error:

```
> node r.js -o generic-profile.js
> Error: Error: EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\xxx\GUI\generic\.svn\entries'
                at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:760:18)
```

I believe the problem is that r.js is attempting to copy the .svn directories from the source folders to the build folders.

Is there a way to exclude .svn directories when running r.js? Can I add something to my build profile, for example?

Here is what my build profile currently look like:

```
({
    "appDir": "../src/generic/",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "dir": "../generic/",
    "include": ["../vendor/require",
                "../vendor/text",
                "../vendor/i18n"],
    "optimize": "uglify2",
    "modules": [
        {
            name: "app"
        }
    ],
    "mainConfigFile": "generic-config.js"
})
```

## Update

Since reading Louis's excellent answer, it's clear that this is not an issue with subversion, but a poorly-configured build profile. I've done some further reading on how to set up a build profile, and [**this example**](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) helped immensely.

If you're having a similar problem, this may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `r.js` already excludes from processing directories that begin with a period. The setting is `fileExclusionRegExp` and the default value is `/^\./` so `.svn` will be skipped. (Looking at the code of `r.js` I see that `fileExclusionRegExp` matches against the basename of each file.)

The error you are seeing is consistent with your input directory coinciding with your output. You do not set `keepBuildDir` to `true`, so your output directory is being removed.  Change your `dir` to build somewhere else.

Or you keep your output under version control. Setting `keepBuildDir` to `true` would take care of the immediate problem but could create more problems down the road if you perform transformations on the output of `r.js`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped massively. Seemed a bit weird that `keepBuildDir` is not true by default, but reading into it, I can see why.